# how to eslint with Vue components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, eslint

I have a .vue file that defines a component. 
Other .vue files cannot seem to see it properly for the linter.
I get many ES Lint errors like:

```
Cannot find module '../components/LinkButton'.
```

I have been through the steps such as

1. Add a custom `// @vue/component` just above my component
   https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue#attention
2. make sure the `html` plugin isn't included
   https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue#why-doesnt-it-work-on-vue-file
3. latest eslint and plugin

`"eslint": "^5.3.0",
  "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0-beta.3",`

Not sure what else to try. My client .eslintrc is as below.

````
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
  },

  "parserOptions": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "ecmaVersion": 2017,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  // extends: 'vue',
  extends: 'plugin:vue/base',

  // required to lint *.vue files
  plugins: [
    'vue',
  ],
  // add your custom rules here
  'rules': {
    'space-before-function-paren': "off",
    'no-multi-spaces': 'off',
    // allow paren-less arrow functions
    'arrow-parens': 0,
    // allow async-await
    'generator-star-spacing': 0,
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": 0,
    "comma-dangle": 0,
    "padded-blocks": 0,
    // allow debugger during development
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 2 : 0
  }
}
```
````

and the component is defined as follows

```
<script>
// @vue/component
const LinkButton = {
  name: 'LinkButton',
  props: [
    'label',
    'link',
    'type',
    'icon'
  ],
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'NLP testing'
    }
  }
}

module.exports = {LinkButton}

</script>
```

and imported with

```
import {LinkButton} from '../components/LinkButton'
```

Note that the file compiles OK with webpack, this is just a linting issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use export default / import syntax from es2017?

Comment: I tried that as well, same problem. I thought being more explicit might help, but no...

Answer (score 2):

The `parser` property of the eslint configuration should be at the root, not within `parserOptions`.

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2017,
    "sourceType": "module"
  }
  // ...
```

It's also unnecessary to specify `vue` in the `plugins` as it's already done by the inherited `plugin:vue/base` config.

Also note that the [configuration file format must be specified in the file name](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring).

> ## Configuration File Formats
>
> ESLint supports configuration files in several formats:
>
> - **JavaScript** - use `.eslintrc.js` and export an object containing your configuration.
> - **YAML** - use `.eslintrc.yaml` or `.eslintrc.yml` to define the configuration structure.
> - **JSON** - use `.eslintrc.json` to define the configuration structure. ESLint’s JSON files also allow JavaScript-style comments.
> - **Deprecated** - use `.eslintrc`, which can be either JSON or YAML.
> - **package.json** - create an `eslintConfig` property in your `package.json` file and define your configuration there.

In your case, you should name the file `.eslintrc.js` since you're exporting a node module.

For eslint to load Vue files correctly, as in using the same webpack configuration, it's needed to explicitely specify the `import/resolver` setting within the eslint configuration file.

```
settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
        webpack: {
            config: 'webpack.conf.js', // if at the project root
        },
    },
},
```

This is used by the [`eslint-import-resolver-webpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-webpack) module which should be installed as well.

Comment: well that changes things, but for the worse. Now the linter fails on any Vue like code eg            `<el-tree
          :props="treeProps"
` it will mark the `:props` colon as unexpected character...

Comment: @dcsan I have added more information to help with the default configuration, the next step would be to adjust rules so it lints only what you need linting.

Comment: where does the import/resolver stuff go? into the .eslint.js or into a webpack config file somewhere? FWIW i'm using a fairly complex template from https://quasar-framework.org/

Comment: @dcsan It's within the eslint configuration that you need to specify where the webpack configuration is, so ESLint can verify the import statements.